# Alternating arms for front crawl

Tags: technique, swimming

I have started taking swimming lessons.
My teacher tells me to alternate arms, in the sense of having 1 arm extended in front of me, not moving, while the other is propulsing me. He wants me to wait for the propulsing arm to also be fully extended at the front to start my downswing of the other. In other words, my hands should join in front before I more to propulsion with the other arm.

My previous technique was opposite, I intuitively thought I should have my arms always in motion, never have one "waiting".

Is my teacher technique universally recognized as correct? If so, can someone explain to me why that is? It intuitively feels to me that the arm passively extended in front of me is not utilized fully to be as fast as I could. What am I missing?

Comment: This is looking likely to be closed as off-topic for this site, but fwiw, my not-at-all-qualified opinion is that perhaps your teacher is trying to get you concentrating on using the correct form at a slower pace - ie committing each arm to the full motion, including extending your arm forward, before going to the other - before then speeding things up into an "arms always in motion" technique...

Comment: Thanks for that. I have read the rules carefully and do not understand how this is "off-topic". Is this not a specific question, related to sports?

Comment: "Swimming" is not a *specific, competitive sport*. All questions on Stack Exchange are expected to be specific; the exactness of the question is not an issue here.